# Performance of passing Base64 string vs saving to disk

Tags: .net, base64, arrays

I have a function (legacy VB6 COM that can't be changed/replaced) that accepts either a Base64 string representation of a file or a UNC or local path to a file.

These values come in from an WFC API call from our customers either as a byte array or as a file path.  If the file comes in as a byte array, we currently convert the byte array into a base64 string to pass into the function.

The problem arises in that if the customer passes in too many very large files, we run out of memory on the server sometimes.  Our temporary solution to this is to, instead of converting to base64, always just save the byte array to disk into a temp directory and then pass in the local file path into the function.

My question is, is there a point of diminishing returns here?  I'm sure it'll be better to save to disk if it's a very large file but if it's a 100kb file, would it be faster and more efficient to just convert to base64 still and pass it in that way?  Meaning, I could check the length of the byte array and if the file is less than, for example, 400kb convert to base64 and if more than 400kb, save to disk?

Comment: We don't have your server neither your data. [The classical blog post from Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) applies here

Comment: This is retail software that is deployed to any number of configurations so we'd never know the server or the data either.  So I was looking for things that can be counted on like "saving to disk is always better than converting to base64 because of XYZ" or vice versa.  Or just a rule of thumb.  Obviously base64-ing a 5MB file from multipe calls isn't better than just saving it to disk. Most customers would probably have some kind of dual core w/ ~8GM ram (which is pretty standard, I guess).